# .htaccess allow sub directories

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

This is my folder structure

```
testsite/index.php
testsite/css/style.css
testsite/.htaccess
```

The problem:
Whenever I goto `http://localhost/testsite/` it loads the css fine.
But whenever I goto `http://localhost/testsite/abc/test/` the css does not render because it is trying to get it from testsite/abc/test/css.

I would rather not use the full web address to each file or have to dynamically test the hierarchy level then go ../css/style.css

Thanks so much in advanced,

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the base tag to the head tag in each of your pages :

```
<base href="/testsite/">
```

This way, the browser will prepend all the css in that page by `/testsite/`.

For more informations about the base tag, [see documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp)

Comment: Thanks very much. You are absolutely right. Instead I put the whole address: localhost/testsite/ and no matter how deep the url goes it does fine. However I would like to know how to edit .htaccess to achieve this :) I would +1 you but I'm a newbie!

Comment: No worries about the +1 ;), and you can't do this with the htaccess, this is the only way

Comment: Kool. That seems odd. What about RewriteBase. But thanks heaps, this works just fine :)

Comment: RewriteBase works for the rules inside the htaccess, not the links in your html files ;)